# Table Value parameter equivalent in Mysql for c#

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

wanted to ask if there is any Table Value parameter equivalent in MySQL through c# ADO.Net.

aim is to send list of custom object to mysql stored procedure at once in an attempt to make the whole process a little more efficient.

any help appreciated